# Seed Django + Postgres with .sql file

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a .sql file which I'd like to seed my django + postgres app with on build. That way I'll have some data in my app during development.

Here's my docker stuff:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 0):

Django supports this usecase with fixtures: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/
You can serialize your .sql database into a json file and feed that during build with the loaddata command.